# The quotient space of U(n)/SO(m)

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, quotient-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

Is there some good way to understand a quotient space of 
$$
U(n)/SO(m)=?
$$
say $n=16$ and $m=10$?

> Can it be some kind of more familiar manifold? What it is?

- The Lie algebra generators of $U(n)$ for the numerator is 256.
- The Lie algebra generators of $SO(m)$ for the numerator is 45 here.

Comment: Other than some very small dimensional examples, I wouldn't expect anything nice.  I do think it's true that $U(n)/SO(m)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times (SU(n)/SO(m))$ for any $m\leq n$, but I don't think $SU(n)/SO(m)$ is generally diffeomorphic to anything else.

Comment: The quotient may well depend on the embedding besides. When there is a preferred embedding sometimes the quotient has a night geometric interepretation. For example, forgetting the complex part of a unitary structure in $n$ complex dimensions defines an embedding $U(n) \hookrightarrow SO(2n)$, and we may interpret the quotient $SO(2n) / U(n)$ as the space of complex structures compatible with an inner product and orientation on $\Bbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: @Travis:  Great point about the embedding, I keep reading it as $SU(n)/SO(n)$ (that is, $m = n$), for which I believe there is a unique embedding, up to conjugacy.  (And my first comment needs to be ammended - there is no way that $U(n)/SO(2)$ is always diffeomorphic to $S^1\times (SU(n)/SO(2))$ since, at least for some embeddings, $U(n)/SO(2)$ is diffeomorphic to $PSU(n)$.

Comment: Annie: The special case $m = n$ (with the usual embedding---Jason, I think that you're right that it's unique up to conjugacy) results in a Riemannian symmetric space that can be interpreted as the space of real structures on $\Bbb C^n$ fixing a given complex determinant. I don't know a description of it in terms of familiar manifolds, but it is clearly connected, and, using a long exact sequence in homotopy for a fibration, we can deduce that it is simply connected and that $\pi_2(SU(n) / SO(n)) \cong \pi_1(SO(n))$, so is $\Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$ for $n > 2$ and $\Bbb Z$ for $n = 2$.